# How to authenticate for Google Cloud App Engine task handlers

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I have an App Engine worker that handles requests for my Google Cloud Tasks queue. How can I verify a request from my task queue, since it allows requests from any other host or client?

I try reading App Engine task `request headers` but I think it NOT enough for authenticating the request.

Further more, how can I verify a request from the same Google cloud project (like `internal` services)?

Comment: Might this be what you want ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/automatic-oauth2-using-cloud-scheduler-and-tasks-to-call-google-apis-55f0a8905baf ... it seems to document a mechanism to validate that a caller of a service (eg. Cloud Tasks) is who it claims to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [request headers](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers#reading_app_engine_task_request_headers) is the best way to authenticate the request is coming from Cloud Tasks. App Engine will strip headers from the request that try to mimic internal headers, like `X-AppEngine-QueueName`.

Unfortunately, in Python 3 there isn't a way to restrict to authenticated users like in [Python 2.7 `app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_login).

Lastly if this doesn't suffice, I recommend adding/signing your own [JWT](https://jwt.io/) to the request header and authenticating it in your App Engine handler.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial shared by Kolban is for HTTP Target task handlers. I understand that you are using App Engine task handlers.

App Engine task handlers does not support "oauthToken" and "oidcToken" fields [link](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks).

According to the official documentation you would have to secure you task handle  URLs to prevent malicious external calls [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers#reading_request_headers).

For example:

```
 handlers:
 - url: /your-task
   script: worker.app
   login: admin
```

You can find more information: [Creating App Engine task handlers](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers)

Comment: That maybe exactly what I need, but I have issue with login argument
```
- url: /worker/.*
  script: auto
  login: admin
```
error:
```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: login for handler '/worker/.*' is not allowed in runtime python37.
```

Comment: I think the example is for python2. For python3 use script: auto [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_script)

Comment: Yes I use script auto, but it not allow `login` argument

Comment: the example is for python2.7, the login argument is not present in python3.

Answer (score 0):

It would also be possible to verify the IP address the request.

Such as;

```
router.get('/task-handler', (req,res) => {
  let ip = req.headers['x-appengine-user-ip']
  if (ip !== '0.1.0.2') {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  }
  // trusted
})
```