# How to Authenticate CloudTasksClient in App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

I am migrating my existing java application to google cloud app engine. The application creates threads on periodic basis to perform certain background tasks. As App Engine does not support threads hence I have to use "Tasks".

I could not find any sample code that uses an application (running in app engine) to create and send task to task handler (also running in app engine).
Sample code available on internet uses client code (task creater) running on local machine and using authentication (via setting key json path in environment variable). In my case I want task creater and task handle both to run on app engine.

My question is: Where can I find a sample code that programmatically authenticates and creates tasks? Basically CloudTasksClient needs to be authenticated programmatically.

Comment: No authentication is needed from GAE standard.  It just works.  Might also be the same for GAE flexible but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I am giving some documentation links that can help with [creating](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks#java) and [handling](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers) the tasks using App Engine.

Please find an example of creating a task with [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#token). Additionally this stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242725/how-to-authenticate-for-google-cloud-app-engine-task-handlers) may help.